# Convert A Firebase Method To Async Await

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have this firebase method that creates a firebase user using a email and password

```
async register(name, email, password,type) {
    let id;
    const createUser = this.functions.httpsCallable('createUser');

    return await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword({email,password })
      .then((newUser)=>{
        id = newUser.user.uid;
        newUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: name
        })
      })
      .then(()=>{
        createUser({
          id:id,
          name:name,
          email:email,
          type:type
        })
      })
  }
```

It also adds the user to a firestore collection using a cloud function that takes the user details and user type.

I have 3 Promises (

1. `createUserWithEmail...()`
2. `updateUserProfile()1`
3. `createUser()`

) which Are dependent on each other.. How do I use them in one function?

**NB**: Couldn't use the `functions.auth.user().onCreate()` method because of the user type field

How do I write this method without using the `.then()` ? 
Some users aren't appearing in the database

Comment: If I got you correctly, some users are not in DB so it doesn't enter the `.then` clause and this is the problem.
If I'm correct in describing it, then the solution is to use the `.catch` clause, which will enter on a rejected promise. If code won't go in the `then` clause it means the promise is rejected, use the `.catch(reason)` to handle it. Also, in your code, you mix the `aync-await` syntax with native promises. the `await` pauses the function's execution until promise is resolved or rejected. you do not even need the `.then` if you use `await`.

Comment: it seems odd that you (always) call `createUser` AFTER `updateProfile` - are both of these functions asynchronous AND do they both return a Promise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to remove `.then` simply use `await` "better"

```
async register(name, email, password,type) {
    let id;
    const createUser = this.functions.httpsCallable('createUser');

    const newUser = await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword({email,password });
    id = newUser.user.uid;
    // assuming the next two functions are asynchrnous AND return a promise
    // if not, just remove await
    await newUser.user.updateProfile({displayName: name});
    await createUser({
        id:id,
        name:name,
        email:email,
        type:type
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks... How Do I add a fail safe incase one of the promises and reject all?

Comment: You can wrap awaits in try-catch

Comment: if you need a fail safe i'd stick with the `.then` and just add a .catch at the end of promise chain. it'd be more readable, and try-catch will catch the rejected promise as a "unhandled promise rejection" error, and you will lose the original "reason" for the promise rejection. Also, a single `catch` would suffice since if comes after a promise chain- a single `.catch` would handle all rejections.

Comment: @Dennis I presume you mean one of the promises fail and then reject all? If so, wrap all your `Promises` in one `Promise` (the `register` function returns a `Promise`) and then for each `Promise` use `.then().catch()` and inside the `catch` bloc `reject()` the wrapper `Promise`.

Comment: Thank You One Final Question: How would a return statement affect the method and where would I place it ?

Comment: @Dennis Even better, just wrap all your awaits in the `register` function in a `try/catch` and if any one of the promises rejected, it will be catched and then do your fail logic.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put any error handling in the code, as there was none in the question - of course, `resgister(.....).catch(e => console.error)` would handle any errors anyway